# Prove that element has following property

Tags: abstract-algebra

Hi i have a problem with following task. 
I tried to find how this property is called in English but i failed. So i need to prove that if $a+b \sqrt{d}$ can't be written as $x\cdot y$ where $x$ and $y$ are not units, then $a-b\sqrt{d}$ can't as well. 
I have no idea how should i even start and will be very glad for help.

Comment: This process is called factorization.

Comment: When I was teaching algebra, the word I used for an element that was not the product of two nonunits was “indecomposable” or “irreducible”. You’re asking for a proof that $z$ indecomposable implies that $\overline z$ is irreducible, where $\overline{a+b\sqrt d}=a-b\sqrt d$. But since $z\mapsto\overline z$ is an automorphism (and has an inverse operation), the result follows.

Comment: I would say that since $a-b\sqrt{d} = 2a-(a+b\sqrt{d})$ it could be derived.

Comment: So automorphism leads irreducible elements on irreducible elements so we have what we wanted. But i haven't got them yet so i am afraid that i can't use it.